# Python Need to capslock on before the input

Tags: python

I want my python application to automatically on the CAPSLOCK so that when the user input the data it is in uppercase.

Actually i was trying to find if there is special library that helps on this.
As this is just a basic function i was able to resolve with the help of you all.

Comment: That's very system-dependent. How about upper-casing everything that the user entered after that?

Comment: How about we get a look at your code?

Comment: why not take input as it is and convert it into uppercase?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just make the input uppercase:

```
>>> s = "this is ANY Case"
>>> s.upper()
'THIS IS ANY CASE'
```

Comment: Thank you. this helped to resolve this